# Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid exception

Tags: vb.net

I keep getting this annoying message (even though it is my fault):

> Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.

I get this message when I am debugging in VB 2010 Express and I hit the "SLM" button.  What the heck does this mean and what am I doing wrong?!?!

My code:

```
Public Class frmAssignment_5

    Private Sub btnSLM_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSLM.Click
        Dim Description As String
        Dim Year As String
        Dim Life As String
        Dim SLMDepreciation As String
        Dim SLMText As String = "straight-line"

        txtDescription.Clear()
        txtYear.Clear()
        txtCost.Clear()
        txtLife.Clear()
        lstResult.ClearSelected()

        Description = CStr(txtDescription.Text)
        Year = CStr(txtYear.Text)
        Life = CStr(txtLife.Text)
        SLMDepreciation = CStr(SLMD())

        lstResult.Items.Add("Description: " & Description)
        lstResult.Items.Add("Year of purchase: " & Year)
        lstResult.Items.Add("Cost: " & FormatCurrency(CStr(txtCost.Text), 2))
        lstResult.Items.Add("Estimated life: " & Life)
        lstResult.Items.Add("Method of depreciation: " & SLMText)


    End Sub

    Function SLMD() As Double
        Dim Salvage_Value As Integer = 0
        Dim Life As String = CStr(txtLife.Text)
        Dim Cost As String = CStr(txtCost.Text)

        SLMD = (CDbl(txtCost.Text) - Salvage_Value) / CDbl(Life)

        Return SLMD
    End Function
End Class
```

The error keeps happening at the "SLMD = (CDbl(txtCost.Text) - Salvage_Value) / CDbl(Life)" but when I change things around, it starts pointing at the things that I change with the same error.

If anyone can help me out, I will be in forever debt...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB is complaining because you are trying to convert an empty String "" value to a number. If you put VAL() around each string, it will convert it to zero.

Salvage_Value is also declared as an Integer, but you are using it as a Double, so you need to convert that too when calculating SLMD:

```
SLMD = (Val(txtCost.Text) - CDbl(Salvage_Value)) / Val(Life)
```

You also have a risk of a division by zero error if "Life" is not set to a value, so you should add code to make sure a value is entered there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried the VAL(), but did not work.  VB still gave me the same error.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Hmm you are mix and matching data types. Try this:

    SLMD = (CDbl(Val(txtCost.Text)) - CDbl(Salvage_Value)) / CDbl(Val(Life))

Make sure "Life" has a non-zero value of course.

Comment: @Shinobi1173 If this is the answer that you used, You need to accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. I am sure SSS would appreciate it. :)

Comment: Why are you using `CDbl` on all of those? `Val` returns a `Double`.

Comment: minitech - you're right, I've removed the superfluous CDbls from my answer

Answer (score 3):

This is very similar to a question I just answered. When you use CDbl to convert a string it will error out if the conversion is not possible, what I would do is use [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) and set the values individually, then if there was an error I would handle it.

```
Function SLMD() As Double
    Dim Salvage_Value As Integer = 0
    Dim Life As Double
    Dim Cost As Double
    If Not Double.TryParse(txtLife.Text, Life) Then
        'Do something to handle error
    End If
    If Not Double.TryParse(txtCost.Text, Cost) Then
        'Do something to handle error
    End If

    Return (Cost - Salvage_Value) / Life

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much but the same old result remained.  It's still giving me that stupid error.

Comment: @Shinobi1173 My mistake, try changing Decimal.TryParse with Double.TryParse

Comment: Yeah, I tried Double.TryParse and still not working.  I am almost thinking my computer is possessed.

Comment: @Shinobi1173 where are you getting the error and what is the exact error code?

Comment: @Shinobi1173 You need to put a breakpoint on the function and step through it. I double checked it and it does work.

Comment: I am not totally sure what a breakpoint is.  Please tell me so I can run with VICTORY!

Comment: There is no error code but I am getting this as the header "InvalidCastException was unhandled"

Comment: @Shinobi1173 I am presuming that you are using Visual Studio. If you click in the Margin to the left of the Function Declaration you will see a dark red circle appear this is a breakpoint, the program will stop at that location. Then if you have the default settings F11 should step you through the program. You can then look at your variables by hovering your mouse over them. See this [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k80ex6de.aspx)

Comment: @Shinobi1173 can you post current code of the SLMD function that you are using now?

Comment: I, with the help of this thread, have gotten it to work.  Mark, I can see that you have thousands of posts under your belt and I now know why.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're changing trying to convert an empty `String` (`""`) to a `Double` at `CDbl(txtCost.Text)`. This is not a valid conversion because "" is not a valid `Double` value.

I think you should be checking your `txtCost.Text` to see if it's actually a `Double` represented as a `String` before attempting the conversion. You could try to block invalid characters/values from the client or check it from the server after you receive it (but before you attempt the conversion). Another option would be to handle it in a [try+catch+finally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) statement. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440339/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-converting-string-to-double) might help as well with what you're encountering.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I believe that I have to stick within the guidelines of what I've learned so far in the class (I'm sorry, but I forgot to mention that this is a homework assignment).  We have not gotten to the try+catch+finally statement yet.

Comment: @Shinobi1173 no worries, I should have noticed from your class name. Sorry for not reading your question more carefully. In that case you might want try the second link I included in my answer, which is the same suggestion as what @MarkHall mentions in his answer. @SSS's [suggestion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) may also work, but might give you (and the user) some unexpected results since the input does not *have* to be a `Double` for it to work.